# Ajax não executando event sucess

Tags: jquery, ajax

Recebi reclamações de alguns clientes que o site não estava concluindo o pedido, mas ao verificar o código não achei nada de mais e para mim funciona perfeitamente. O código do ajax é esse

```
$.ajax({
                type      : 'POST', 
                url       : 'www.site.com/functions.php', 
                data      : {func: func, nome: nome, email: email, cel: cel, tamanho: tamanho, modelo: modelo, valor: valor}, 
                dataType  : 'json',
                timeout   : 30000,
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(){
                  $('div.loading').fadeIn(400);
                },
                complete: function(response){
                  $('div.loading').fadeOut(400);
                  avancar_container(id);
                  alert(response);
                },
                success: function(response){
                  $('div.loading').fadeOut(400);
                  avancar_container(id);
                  alert(response);
                },
                error: function(response){
                  alert(response);
                }
            });
```

o estranho é que o pedido é registrado no banco de dados, o que me descarta erro no php, porém a pessoa não recebe a mensagem de sucesso.

Comment: Os dados são gerados no banco de dados corretamente? Já tentou deixando alguns campos sem preencher? O que `error` e `complete` retornam? Já verificou os logs de erro do `php` e do seu servidor? A requisição está atingindo o tempo limite? Já verificou a aba console do "Inspetor de Elemento" ou similar?

Comment: Os dados no bd são corretos, o jquery e o php fazem verificação de campos. A mensagem retorna o echo do php corretamente. O timeout estou testando agora, e parece funcional. Os logs e inspetor ainda nao olhei

Comment: Você tem dois `alert()` após o retorno? o `complete` sempre será executado ao final, seja do sucesso ou erro. Como ele tem as mesmas instruções do `success`, será que você não está confundindo?

Comment: eu coloquei o complete depois para ver se funcionava, mas não adiantou, esqueci de mudar quando publiquei.